# using st_distance in sql to find nearby rows

Tags: mysql, sql, gis

I have an SQL table with `lat`, `long` columns. I am trying to search through the table to find rows that are nearby a `POINT`.

First step I did was to create a new column `coords` with `Lat`, `Long` coordinates.

```
Table1

name   Lat        Long         
post   37.788151  -122.407570  
sutter 37.789551  -122.408302  
oak    37.815730  -122.288810  


ALTER TABLE schema_name.table1 ADD coords Point;

UPDATE schema_name.table1 SET coords = Point(`Long`, Lat);
```

Query to find rows that are within `<500ft` distance condition:

```
select * from schema_name.table1 
where st_distance(Point(-122.4104907, 37.789551), coords) <= 500;
```

First question is, what unit do I express the distance in? How do I convert from miles? I used `meters` and do not get any results. The `Point` is within `500ft` distance.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance

Comment: *what unit do I express the distance in? How do I convert from miles?* Depends on SRID value. *Query to find rows that are within <500ft distance condition* Recommendation - add a condition which selects the rows which have the distance to the desired point not more than needed distance by one coordinate only (maybe in subquery) - this will decrease the amount of spatial calculations.

Comment: The conversion between coordonate difference and distance is not constant and depends on the distance from the equator. If your points are relatively close together you could use a static value and simplify your work.

Comment: @Kendle Points are not relatively close in reality, I am just sharing sample data on SO.

Comment: See https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html to calulate a static value or find the formulas. I think that they could be simplified!

Comment: @Akina SRID value is 0. Could you respond with implementation details? How do I use `st_distance` to find rows that meet the condition?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, name VARCHAR(255), Latitude DECIMAL(10,6), Longtitude DECIMAL(10,6));
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> (1, 'post',   37.788151,  -122.407570),  
> (2, 'sutter', 37.789551,  -122.408302),  
> (3, 'oak',    37.815730,  -122.288810);
> ALTER TABLE test ADD coordinates Point;
> UPDATE test SET coordinates = Point(Longtitude, Latitude);
> SELECT id, name, Latitude, Longtitude, ST_AsText(coordinates) FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | name | Latitude | Longtitude | ST_AsText(coordinates) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | post | 37.788151 | -122.407570 | POINT(-122.40757 37.788151) |
> | 2 | sutter | 37.789551 | -122.408302 | POINT(-122.408302 37.789551) |
> | 3 | oak | 37.815730 | -122.288810 | POINT(-122.28881 37.81573) |

> ```
> SELECT t1.name, t2.name, ST_Distance_Sphere(t1.coordinates, t2.coordinates)
> FROM test t1
> JOIN test t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
> ```
>
> | name | name | ST_Distance_Sphere(t1.coordinates, t2.coordinates) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | post | sutter | 168.4384736143564 |
> | sutter | oak | 10894.417360668858 |
> | post | oak | 10875.419213829204 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9dbd6b000dcd01fb62852293a00d1269)*

The distance is calculated in meters. The values seems to be correct (checked with Yandex.Map ruler).